# Keywords in a paper: to include or not to include?

Tags: publications, keywords

Are there some reasons to include them besides a historical tradion? Let's assume that it's not a requirement by the publisher.

There are some answers (such as [this](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/49095/32707)) which claim that keywords basically do not matter. However, I wonder if there are some empirical results or conflicting opinions on this. Perhaps they help with search engines?

My field is computer science, publishing mostly in IEEE conferences. Feel free to share experiences from other fields.

Comment: I cannot think of any downside to including keywords but there are possible positive things (better categorization) so no reason to not include them.

Comment: One is space that can be used for something else: consider a 6 page conference paper - sometimes we need to apply various tricks to ft *everything* there. Another is that they may be distracting or annoying for the reader ("Gosh, yet another bunch of buzzwords!").

Comment: space? That's one line of text. If that's a problem then something else is seriously wrong. And how can it distraxt or annoy anyone if there are some keywords listed somewhere below author adress or at the end after acknowledgements like it's common to do. And you might want to use keywords, not buzzwords..

Comment: @DSVA This is perhaps an extreme example, with two types of keywords  that in total takes approx. as much space as 10 % of the body text of the publication: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.186.3039&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: then I don't understand why that's a problem here but the incredible waste of space by putting contact information of all the authors in there isn't, since you could save nearly a whole column if you put the authors below the title and only give contact to the corresponding author. On the other hand I personally don't think there's any wasted space here.

Comment: @DSVA I don't think the authors of *that particular paper* tried to save space; hence, the large number of keywords they use.

Comment: Many journals online systems won't even let you submit the paper if you don't give keywords. Btw., before your paper is very well read, search engines will have problems extracting *key* words from the text. Doesn't hurt to help google a bit, there.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one reason to include them:

In some fields, like biology, naming convention are lacking. You might use a specific word for a process, while other groups use another. By stating this other word in your keywords, researchers using that word will find your article/conference.

Answer (score 2):

The answer you linked to actually lists two reasons, why keywords DO make sense (esp. number two) ;)

I always assumed that the keywords you specify in the webinterface during submission are the important ones, that will be used to catalog your submission. I do not think that the ones you specify on the title page are of any relevance nowadays. Thus, if you are asking about the keywords on the tile page, in order to shorten your publication by removing them, I guess this is reasonable, unless the formatting guidlines of the conference explicitly states them as needed.