# Is it beneficial to prefer keywords complementary to words in the title?

Tags: publications, writing, google-scholar, keywords

This was some advice given by an editor in a writing course:

> If there is a limit to the number of keywords, don’t use terms already used in the title. Rather, use terms that are complementary, synonymous, or equivalent (even “non-standard” terms) to those in the title. This will allow your paper to appear in more searches in Google Scholar and similar search engines.

Is this correct?

Comment: I don't know how often this is recommended, but it makes good sense.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because one would have to analyze the frequency with which this advice is given.  Pretty impossible for us to say.

Comment: @aparente001: Well, you could theoretically analyse the frequency. More importantly, the answer to the question is irrelevant and what actually matters to every sane person is whether this advice is correct. As I presume the asker to be a sane person, I will just edit the question accordingly.

Comment: Relevant and similar question: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/49093/what-is-appropriate-number-of-keywords-for-conference-paper

Answer (score 1):

Key-words are crucial for indexing, whereas the words chosen for the title and the abstract are impactful for free text searches.

For instance, you may search [PubMed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/) with key-words (using the [mh] tag), with title words (using the [ti] tag), with title or abstract words (using the [tiab] tag), and so forth.

In case you use in the title and abstract words which correspond to indexing terms, then you may find reasonable to use alternative words as key-words. However, the most important thing is to use, in at least one of the venues (key-words, title, or abstract), the accepted indexing terms.

Comment: Joe please roll back if my edit is not correct.